# Java splitting a string with newlines into an array, where the string is read from a file using buffered reader

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, split

I'm loading a file into a buffer which is loaded into a string buffer.  I'm then copying this string buffer into a string.  The string prints out as...

> Sam
>
> ravon
>
> Ashley
>
> annie

So I want to make an array for this string so I can put the first line and second line at a time into a function that creates a node for a LinkedList that takes a username and password ... ex Username: Sam , Password: ravon.  This is then loaded into a LinkedList.  All of my functionally is working when it comes to the LinkedList, but I can't seem to split my string into an array.

I thought something like...

`String[] userContent = content.split("\n")` would place each element of content into userContent[n] string where

`userContent[0] = Sam, userContent[1] = ravon` and etc.  However, this is not the case.

code I'm using  - It takes a linked list and file name as arguments

```
    public static void readUserFile(String fName, LinkedList<dataUser> ll) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fName);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }

        LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("userData.txt")));
        lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        lnr.close();
        fileReader.close();
        int realSize = lnr.getLineNumber();
        //String[] userContent = line.split("\n");
        String content = stringBuffer.toString();
        String[] userContent = content.split("/n");

         //this prints nothing, would expect it to print exactly what content prints
        for(int i = 0; i < realSize; i++) {
            System.out.println(userContent[i]);
        }

        /*  this is what I want to load the userContent string into
        //not working
        for(int i = 0; i < realSize; i++) {
            dataUser tempUser = new dataUser(userContent[i],            userContent[i+1]);
            ll.add(tempUser);
            i = i + 1;
        }*/

        //System.out.println(content);  //works and prints the file with new lines
        //System.out.println("Contents of file:");
        //System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Why don't you just fill an `ArrayList` of strings while you are reading instead of appending to a `StringBuffer`?

Comment: Oh, and your problem is that you are splitting by `/n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: readAllLines will place it into one giant string?   I haven't used Java before so I've only played with the LinkedList library so far in java.

Comment: Ah that was it RealSkeptic, thanks for noticing the error.  I also forgot to add +1 to realSize to account for 0 in the array size.

Comment: You didn't address RealSkeptic's previous comment. What you're doing doesn't make any sense, especially what you're doing with the LineNumberReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now you are only checking for whitespaces,

```
split("\n")
```

use %%n for new lines, 
or you can use %%W
which is not alphanumeric characters
happy coding

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth the following will do the same thing your code is doing without creating/splitting a String and reopening a file unnecessarily and also won't thrown an exception if you happen to run into a file with a user but no password.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fName));
String user;

while ((user = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String pass = br.readLine();
    if (pass == null) {
        System.out.println("Warning: User found with no password: " + user);
        break;
    }
    ll.add(new DataUser(user, pass));
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question?

Comment: The OP has additional issues, for example the hard coding of "userData.txt" instead of using fName and using i+1 while iterating over an array. All that code is completely unnecessary.